# Two factor authentication for Microsoft outlook

Tags: authentication, outlook, exchange-server

Is there any way to provide two factor authentication for Microsoft Outlook client. It may use ISA server or any other. Basically 2-factor authentication is possible for OWA but I haveb't been able to find a way to implement it for Microsoft Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work, you would have to change the authentication method in Exchange.  This is easy to do in packages like postfix a la:http://www.wikidsystems.com/support/wikid-support-center/how-to/how-to-configure-webmail-for-wikid-strong-authentication/, however, I bet it would a lot harder for Exchange.